# Preciso saber o tamanho de um arquivo mesmo antes de ser criado

Tags: python, algoritmo, python-2.7

Estou com um trabalho da faculdade e tá difícil de resolver... é tipo aquelas wordlists que os hackers usam, mas é pra estudo didático.

***QT: Gere um arquivo com todos os agrupamentos possíveis usando o conceito de arranjos simples no qual temos n elementos arranjados p a p, com n >= p. Antes de gerar o arquivo informe uma saída dizendo quantos arranjos e tamanho o arquivo possui.***

Ex:

> Foram geradas x arranjos e o tamanho do arquivo é y (bytes, MB, GB ou
>   TB). Deseja continuar, [S]im ou [N]ão?

Eu não sei nem como começar, porque como é que calculo o total de bytes sem mesmo ter criado o arquivo. Complicado. A maneira que pensei foi calcular o total de arranjos que daria "tantas" linhas e em cada linha teria 7 bytes, se cada linha é 7 bytes, multiplico pelo total de arranjos possíveis.

Fórmula:

> A(n!/(n-p)!)

Ex:

> A(22!/(22-7)!) = A(22!/(15)!) = 859.541.760 milhões de palavras arranjados 7 a 7 
>   de 22 elementos

*Agora pego esse resultado e multiplico por 7 que daria o total de bytes e eu faria a conversão para os demais tamanhos. 
Agora por que eu multipliquei por 7? Porque cada caractere vale 1 byte, tirando os caracteres com acentos e o arranjo de todas as linhas são com 7 caracteres.*

O problema mesmo é esse, calcular o tamanho do arquivo.

Comment: Dependendo da estrutura do seu arranjo, ele pode ser o tamanho do seu arquivo, se seu arranjo estiver em `string`, use o `len` para pegar o tamanho, quando for escrever no arquivo o tamanho será o mesmo

Comment: No modulo `sys` tem o método [getsizeof()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) que permite obter o tamanho de um objeto em bytes, acredito que este método pode ajudar você a obter o tamanho de um objeto que sera o conteúdo de um determinado arquivo antes de sua criação.

Answer (score 1):

Pra gerar um arquivo de texto você precisa de uma string.

```
texto = 'eu faço\nperguntas\nno SO-pt'
```

Você consegue gerar a representação binária da string com um encoding.

```
btexto = texto.encode('utf8')
```

Uma vez que você tem a string binária, use `len` para contar os bytes.

```
n_bytes = len(btexto)
```

Quando for gravar o arquivo, não esqueça de usar o modo binário.

```
with open('C:\\teste.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(btexto)
```